# How to build new theme on Hexo and integrate to Vue SSR(Server-Side Rendering)?

Tags: vue.js, themes, webpack-dev-server, hexo

I'm try to build a new theme.I really like Hexo for manager my blog and really love Vue. However, It's no so simple integrate both technologie together. If you have suggestion I can change my workflow if it's so hard.

Comment: This website has some example code to get you started. You're right though it is tricky https://github.com/briangonzalez/briangonzalez.org